# This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: vnc, qt, systemback

I wanted to install Systemback on my ubuntu 20.04 and found [this page](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-systemback-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-18-10).
When I ran systemback, I get this error message.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~$ sudo systemback&
[1] 220231
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~$ No protocol specified
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :2
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

What should I install and how? (fwiw, I'm doing it on a vnc client on a windows 10 machine at work, and connecting to the windows 10 machine from home) Thanks in advance!

ADD : I did `sudo apt install qt5dxcb-plugin` and tried again, it didn't work. (said plugin "xcb"couldn't beload even though it was found) But when I ran it on console window, systemback worked.  I used to run systemback on vnc window too on 16.04 I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a different tool (virtualbox) in ubuntu 20.04 after recent updates. For me the fix was to execute this in the command line:

```
xhost +local:
```

Maybe it should be in some file that is executed always during startup. Reinstalling libxcb-xinerama0 and qt5-default didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using QtCreator. Try executing this command to replace libxcb-xinerama0.so.2

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this while trying to run elctrum from Ubuntu on windows 10. After running ">export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1" I saw that it couldn't open display.
I installed [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and it worked.
The procedure is explained here: [How to run graphical Linux applications on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://www.stat.ipb.ac.id/agusms/index.php/2019/01/15/how-to-run-graphical-linux-applications-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/)
Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoted, I'm guessing, because you provided a link without summarizing its contents here - which would matter if the link went dead - which is what has happened: the page apparently doesn't exist anymore. But there's still an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20221127145024/https://www.stat.ipb.ac.id/agusms/index.php/2019/01/15/how-to-run-graphical-linux-applications-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/ But I would still prefer the explanation, because at first glance I don't see how it works.